# Best solution for pushing remote master to remote dev branch without local dev branch changes

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have two branches (`master` for production and `dev` for development) in both local and remote.

`dev` branch is linked to development server and `master` branch is linked to production server.

I've worked like following algorithm.

1. I'm working on `dev` branch and push to the remote `dev`
   branch.
2. Then I test on the development server and if all are ok, I merge
   local `dev` branch to local `master` branch.
3. Then I push `master` branch to remote `master` branch.

While developing, I've encountered one problem that dev server doesn't work well.
But I think that is not because of code. I think the mistake would be related to the dev server config.
To prove this, I'm going to push `master` branch to remote `dev` branch and check if the dev server works well with production code.
But when I'm trying to push local `master` branch code to remote `dev` branch, the error occured.

```
$ git push origin master:dev
 ! [rejected]        master -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.xxx.xx.xx/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm thinking about `git push -f`, but it's the only solution?

What is the best solution for solving this problem?
Please help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you push your local `master` to remote `dev`, it tries to overwrite your remote `dev` with your local `master` (meaning replace it). As `master` contains merge commits it's different from `dev`, depending on how you merge, commits are different. Try to merge your local `master` (first reset your local `dev` and `master` to remote ones accordingly) to your local `dev` and then push your local `dev` to remote `dev`.
Might happen that you will have some merge conflicts while merging master to dev.

If you will force push any of your local branches to remote (should be even restricted by remote setup), you will loose everything which was on remote before, because force push will overwrite the branch. Be careful with it.

Comment: reset means sync local to remote?
I'm going to push master to dev. but you suggested dev to master?

Comment: @thinkmore sorry, corrected my answer. Reset means sync local to remote, as you can do it with commands:  

    git fetch (to fetch remote)    and then 
    git reset --hard origin master (to reset to remote master).

Comment: but if i do like that, i lost local changes. the purpose is test. if test is okay, i need to rollback. in terms of that, i think ```git reset``` delete all history and change.